# HTML tables side by side (sharepoint) (without CSS/style)

Tags: html, css, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to have two HTML tables side by side on a Sharepoint webpage. I have noticed that Sharepoint strips anything away from in between `<style></style>` tags. Also strips information in `<div><\div>` tags.

I have this, currently.

```
<body>

<div>

<table style="width:40%" border="1px solid black" float="left" width="148px" margin-right=" 4%">
     <caption><a href="#arts">List</a></caption>
    <tr>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>3 TB</td>
     <td>10</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><b>P</b></td>
      <td><b>S</b></td>
     <td><b>U</td>
   </tr>

</table>

<table style="width:40%" border="1px solid black" float="left" width="148px" margin-right=" 4%">
     <caption><a href="#arts">Arts List</a></caption>
    <tr>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>10</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><b>P</b></td>
      <td><b> S</b></td>
     <td><b>U</td>
   </tr>

</table>
/div>
```

Is it even possible to have two HTML tables side by side in sharePoint. (Without `div/style` tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two tables next to each other by floating them left and making the widths small enough to fit horizontally like so:

```
<table style="float:left;width:50%;box-sizing:border-box;">
   ...
</table>
<table style="float:left;width:50%;box-sizing:border-box;">
   ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use nested tables.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <table>
         ...
       </table>
    </td>
    <td>
       <table>
         ...
       </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: the tables wont be side by side on a webpage, using that.

Comment: Yes they would, it's just not very clear in the example. I fixed it up a little.

Answer (score 1):

The style attribute should be one continuous string.
So this

```
<table style="width:40%" border="1px solid black" float="left" width="148px" margin-right=" 4%">
```

should be this

```
<table style="width: 40%; border: 1px solid black; float: left; width: 148px; margin-right: 4%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my job and I do not have the permission to use SharePoint designer; 
To have 2 different tables in a single "Layout Column" I did the following:

1) Create a table with 1 row and 2 columns.

2) Inside each column add the table. The table would fit automatically or you can modify the width and the high on the ribbon.

3) Change the style of the 1st table to "Table Style 1 - Clear" to eliminate the border.